# iphone app settings

Tags: iphone, settings.bundle

I would like to be able to show the app settings to some users and to others no. I have created the settings bundle (the default settings bundle outside the app), it works fine and I know how to access the settings value pragmatically.

What I would like to do is either:

***if(user logged) do nothing else make settings disappear

or:
***if(user logged) create settings pragmatically and make them show
   else make settings disappear/delete

I know I can't make the whole settings invisible is it possible to make one of the pref invisible???

How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

A setting bundle is totally static. You can't run some code in it, like checking if the user is connected.
I pretty sure that you cannot, in your app, activate or deactivate the setting bundle. If I'm wrong, I would be glad to know how.

**EDIT :**

You should create an in-app settings view controller to control dynamically some entries.
There's no automated way to make that kind on settings but I think you should create an UITableViewController.
Here's the documentations : https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451

And a good sample code : https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007318

Comment: you right but what if you create settings pragmatically, I don't even know if it is possible, but if you could do that it in code I would like to know how

Comment: thks for your answer I actually replaced it by a simple alertview and deleted the preference bundle